# Difference result in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, resnet, loss

I use ML for image processing to classify the covid-19 patients based on their X-ray chest images. Using google colab and ResNet101 model, I wonder there can be any probability that the value of accuracy and loss can be different when running multiple times (with the same parameters, datasets and algorithm). For example, when using ResNet101 with 4-folds, image_size=(128, 128), batch_size = 32, num_epochs = 80, learning_rate = 0.00001, layers.Dense = 256, the first time google colab gave out the value of accuracy and loss was 91.07% and 0.292 respectively. But the second time it was 90.36% and 0.346. So is there any probability that the result can be different? And if so, how can I minimize it? If not, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: There is nothing to fix; such *statistical* fluctuations in the results are both normal & expected, and they are due to the inherent randomness of the used algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. But I just wonder that randomness of the algorithms can make a large diffrence. I have just finished the third run and the result was even lower than expected (the accuracy was just 88.57%)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to model weights that are randomly initialized, data sampling order and data augmentation during your training loop and other kind of randomness. One way to "fix" this in order to reproduce your results is to set all your random seeds (python, tf, cuda, ...).